# How to snag customers if what your company does is too hard to explain

Tags: website-design, marketing, landing-page

Some businesses can easily explain themselves:

- "Buy cars at low prices!"
- "The front-end framework for Rickrolling!"
- "Our JUULs are too cool for the pool!"

On the other hand, my website's service is a long, complex process that I can't sum up into a slogan. It takes several paragraphs of explanation for readers to get the gist of "what we do," "how it works," "why choose us," etc. Nobody likes a wall of text on the homepage. How do I get conversions when people have super-short attention spans and won't sit down to read a long article? How do I compete with other sites that have clear value propositions?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate in a marketing or advertising forum, although there is a small element of how UX design can play a part. I think from a user's advocate perspective, the critical thing would be to try and present the value or benefit that your company/business brings to the user rather than trying to explain exactly what is provided (especially if it is hard to explain).

Comment: Why would someone come to your site? What are they trying to accomplish? (Why did you build the site? What tangible problem were you trying to solve?) Base your slogan on that.

Comment: Are (potential) customers likely to know they need a service like yours? A pithy slogan may be needed to "catch" potential customers who didn't know they wanted your services (and probably don't _need_ those services). If what you do is as complex as you imply, it sounds more like most (potential) customers will already know they need your services... if so, I think it's more about appearing on searches for providers of those services than a "pithy slogan". Once they hit your site, knowing they know they need you, you don't need to be a brief when explaining why you are better than the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premium rickrolling also has complex motivations and processes behind them. You just aren't interested in reading several paragraphs of text about it. Or at least not until after you know their slogan and they piqued your interest.

How to compete with sites that have a clear value proposition? Have one yourself. This isn't a UX problem in the sense that this forum means, it's a problem of copywriting.